# Discrepancy in Ruby CLI Option `-p` Behavior with and without Pipe

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

I'm observing different behaviors with the Ruby command-line option `-p` depending on whether it's used with or without a pipe. Here are the two scenarios:

Without Pipe:

- When I run `ruby -pe 'puts "You said #{$_}"`, it seems to just output the input **as it is** after what `puts` prints.

With Pipe:

- However, using a pipe as in `echo "hello world" | ruby -pe '$_.upcase!` results in the expected transformation, printing an upcased "HELLO WORLD".

Can someone explain why there's a difference in behavior between these two scenarios? Is the `-p` option interacting differently with the input in each case?

FYI. The results are below.

```
$ echo "hello world" | ruby -pe '$_.upcase!'
HELLO WORLD
```

```
$ ruby -pe 'puts "You said #{$_}"'
1
You said 1
1
...
```

Comment: It might help to make the examples more alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-p` flag, according to the `ruby(1)` man page, will "print the value of variable `$_` at the each end of the loop.". In your example with the pipe, this is working as you expect: using `upcase!` will replace the value of `$_` and Ruby will print it out afterwards.

However, in your example without a pipe, you're using `puts` to explicitely print out a string, which happens *in addition* to the `-p` behaviour. Using the first example with and without a pipe works the same way:

```
$ ruby -pe '$_.upcase!'
aa
AA
$ echo "aa" | ruby -pe '$_.upcase!'
AA
```

You can also use the `-n` flag, which does the same as `-p` but won't automatically print out anything. For example:

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts "You said #{$_}"'
aa
You said aa
bb
You said bb
cc
You said cc
```

Comment: Thank you Taavi, now I know the reason.
It was because of the bang operator :)

`$ echo "hello world" | ruby -pe '$_.upcase' -> hello world`